# Heading and paragraph text on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to complete the personal portfolio webpage task on freecodecamp, and I've hit a snag.

I have my heading and paragraph text aligned in the middle of the page like I want, however, the paragraph text appears to be ignoring the  element.

I have tried inserting a break line to no avail, and would really appreciate help on this before I move on with completing the challenge.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d3d95;
}

.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-diection: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#projects {}

h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

#navbar {}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

ol {
  display: inline;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #8524e9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #042574;
}
```

```html
<!--nav section-->
<nav id="navbar" class="nav">
  <ul>
    <ol> <a href="#">About<a/></ol>
    <ol> <a href="#">Contact<a/></ol>
    <ol> <a href="#">Projects<a/></ol>
</ul>
    </nav> 
<!--End nav section-->
    
<!--Welcome  Section Start-->
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hey I am Mimic</h1>
  <p>a web developer</p>
</section>
<!--Welcome  Section End-->
<section id="projects">
 
</section>
```

Comment: Typo: `flex-diection`

Comment: ditto:  Hey Ostone0 you promised to show me how to change folder names with a bash shell.  Where's the love?

Comment: Working on it @DCR.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `welcome-section` there should be `flex-direction: column;`, you mispelled it

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in `flex-direction: column;` in the `.welcome-section`. And you have written `flex-diection: column;`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0d3d95;
}

.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#projects {}

h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

#navbar {}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

ol {
  display: inline;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #8524e9;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #042574;
}
```

```html
<!--nav section-->
<nav id="navbar" class="nav">
  <ul>
    <ol> <a href="#">About<a/></ol>
    <ol> <a href="#">Contact<a/></ol>
    <ol> <a href="#">Projects<a/></ol>
</ul>
    </nav> 
<!--End nav section-->
    
<!--Welcome  Section Start-->
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hey I am Mimic</h1>
  <p>a web developer</p>
</section>
<!--Welcome  Section End-->
<section id="projects">
 
</section>
```